# Transform and send a base64 image in attachment with FlaskMailMessage

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-mail

I would like to send an image by email with `FlaskMailMessage`. But this image is a base64 encoded image.

Here is an example code :

```py
def mail_answer():
    msg = "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"

    msg = base64.b64decode(msg)

    attachment = [
        FileStorage(
            stream=io.BytesIO(msg),
            filename="image01.png",
            name="image01.png",
            content_type="image/png",
        )
    ]

    headers = {"Reply-To": "hello@test.com"}

    FlaskMailMessage(
        "SO test",
        sender="achichi@stackoverflow.com",
        recipients=["test@†est.com"],
        extra_headers=headers,
        attachments=attachments,
    )
```

When I try to execute it I have the following error :

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/portail/tools/threading.py", line 33, in run
    super().run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/portail/modules/notification/notifications.py", line 83, in _background_notification_handle
    manager.mail_users(emailed_users, signal.name, obj)
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/portail/modules/helpdesk/notifications.py", line 360, in mail_users
    self.mail_answer(users, ticket)
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/portail/modules/helpdesk/notifications.py", line 465, in mail_answer
    mails.send_email(
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/portail/modules/mail/lib.py", line 297, in send_email
    return mail.send(msg)
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 492, in send
    message.send(connection)
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 427, in send
    connection.send(self)
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 190, in send
    message.as_bytes() if PY3 else message.as_string(),
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 385, in as_bytes
    return self._message().as_bytes()
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_mail.py", line 350, in _message
    f.set_payload(attachment.data)
  File "/Users/antoine/Documents/Git/portail/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3023, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.stream, name)
AttributeError: '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'data'
```

FlaskMail attachments are a `list[FileStorage]`, maybe I do not need `io.BytesIO(msg)` ? But what should I use instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the [Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/#attachments), it's not a FileStorage that's expected,
as the `arguments` parameter, but rather an `Attachment` object (can be seen from the [source code as well](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/blob/master/flask_mail.py#L219)).

So the actual code to attach a file to the message would be :

```py
def mail_answer():
    msg = "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"


    data_bytes = base64.b64encode(msg)

    headers = {"Reply-To": "hello@test.com"}

    msg = FlaskMailMessage(
        "SO test",
        sender="achichi@stackoverflow.com",
        recipients=["test@†est.com"],
        extra_headers=headers
    )
    
    msg.attach("filename.png", "image/png", data_bytes)

    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Indeed, you're right, `Attachment` is the right type ! My `msg` is already a base64, I don't think I need to encode it again ? Furthermore, when I try `msg.attach` I have the following error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`